# Iterative loop in jade isn't rendering data correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I've got a table in jade that'll be dynamically generated through express (`res.render('index', {classes: results})`):

```
table
  tr
    th Title
    th School
    th Description
- if (classes.length) {
- classes.forEach(function(aClass) {
  tr
    td= aClass.title
    td= aClass.school
    td= aClass.desc
- });}
```

However, when I render it, the data comes out as one garbled mess.  Looking at the HTML source reveals that the `</table>` tag is *before* the content in `classes`.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it - jade is being finicky here.  When creating an iterative loop, you need to make sure that your JavaScript is indented to the same level as your data:

```
table
  tr
    th Title
    th School
    th Description
  - if (classes.length) {
  - classes.forEach(function(aClass) {
  tr
    td= aClass.title
    td= aClass.school
    td= aClass.desc
  - });}
```

If this makes your inner coder cringe at the code style, I'm with you.  However, that's the way it is.  Alternatively, you could use jade's `each` ([documented here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#iteration))

```
table
  tr
    th Title
    th School
    th Description
  - if (classes.length) {
  each aClass in classes
    tr
      td= aClass.title
      td= aClass.school
      td= aClass.desc
  - }
```

Again, this looks a little wonky but is the jade way to iterate.

Comment: You can also do similar for the `if` -- just `if classes.length` with `each ...`, etc. indented under it: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

My indentation style is:

```
table
  tr
    th Title
    th School
    th Description
  if (classes.length)
    each aClass in classes
      tr
        td= aClass.title
        td= aClass.school
        td= aClass.desc
```